# Modified abstract and thanks with two front pages

Tags: titles

I have to use a specific format for documents in in LaTeX. I have to use a `.sty` file (`iadb.sty`) and in it is specified the abstract and thanks as follow:

```
%Abstract and Thanks

\let\abstractname@save\abstractname
\let\@addtoThanks\@empty
\def\abstractname{{\normalsize\abstractname@save}\@addtoThanks
\global\let\@makefnmark@special\@makefnmark}
\newcommand{\addtoThanks}[1]{\g@addto@macro\@addtoThanks{\footnote{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Thanks}[1]{\addtoThanks{#1}}
```

But beside using this `.sty` file I need to make two front pages, one with authors and other without authors. I am doing the following but there is an error. What should I do?

```
\documentclass[12pt,openbib]{article}
\usepackage{iadb}
\usepackage{titling}
..
\begin{document}

\title{The Title}
\date{  }
\author{Author1\Thanks{%
University1} 
and Author2\Thanks{%
University2}}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
ABSTRACT
\end{abstract}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\title{The Title}
\date{  }
\author{\emptythanks}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
ABSTRACT
\end{abstract}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to `iadb.sty`?

Comment: I uploaded it to sugarsync here is the link
https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D1123168_147_636842748